# Practices for getting information from $_GET/$_POST and saving it to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

What are today's best practises when it comes to getting information from a get/post and saving information to a database? Is data still escaped like it used to or are there additional practises? Also, where can HTMLPurifier fit in this? I'm currently using it to filter rich text.

Comment: It all depends on what you are going to do with the data. It depends on what kind of escaping needs to be done with it. Can you add some context?

Comment: Hi Pekka. Most of the data will be saved and then later displayed. This is for a social site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Never Save data from GET to db.**

Never ever save data from GET, even if you are doing sufficient validation and escaping. GET is not supposed to change information on server.

**Before changing anything on server (DB or Server File) check if request is POST or PUT or DELETE as applicable**

POST is supposed to change state of the server. Hence before updating your tables or changing any file on server check if request method is post.

**Validate inputs before processing**

If you are expecting an integer validate that input is indeed an integer.

**Escape inputs before using in db queries or adding to output**

For query purposes escape the inputs and in case you are using input to be directly printed to the output then strip the slashes and sanitize it.

**Use perishable tokens for POST when you have privilege of user sessions**

Use access tokens in case you have user logged in and update the token every access or 5mins or so.

**Use access tokens when you don't have user session**

As Ankur suggested use access tokens when you don't have login session. But this is not reliable.

Comment: use $_SERVER attributes like http_referrer to cross check if post is generated from the desired page only.

Comment: Apart from it , you can use access_tokens as another alternative, whenever users open the form page, generate a access_token and make a db entry with that token, make a hidden field with access token. Update that row incase user submits the form else delete that row entry after some time.

Comment: Ashwini, thanks for reminder. Yes, GET shouldn't be used for this purpose and that's why POST is systematically used in forms. I haven't heard of PUT or DELETE though.

Comment: @ankur Using HTTP_REFERER to do any kind of authenticity check is highly dangerous, it can be manipulated freely by the client

Comment: @Pekka: Can HTTP_REFERER be used as added security? I mean as an additional way to confirm that a request is secure.

Comment: @James nope. If your security system needs to protect against an attacker trying to inject data, you can not trust the referrer at all, it can be freely changed.

Comment: @James P. PUT and delete are never integrated in forms. POST requests can handle multiple updates while PUT and DELETE limit to a single resource provided in the request. POST request actions to an already existing resourse on your server eg. "add.php" while put can refer to "/path/new_file" where new_file does not exist. PUT requests needs to have handlers which create or update the /path/new_file and populate it with the content provided.

Answer (score 4):

You should never assume that information from GET or POST is properly escaped, even if you do validation on your website, javascript can be disabled and requests can be manually coded to do an SQL injection attack. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when generating your query string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

As far as I can tell from quickly reading up on it, **HTML Purifier** is to parse output from WYSIWYG editors or anywhere where you're expecting proper HTML from the user. It gives you control to disallow and filter out certain things (like scripts) and makes sure all tags are properly nested and closed. It is especially important if you're dumping the HTML into your page after reading the data back from the database.

Comment: Well, that is if he is using the `mysql_()` family of functions.

Comment: @Pekka - Hmm... true... the post is tagged with mysql though, so I might just be right.

Comment: @Pekka @DarthJDG: I'm not sure but I think so. Some sort of database class is being used. Also, HTMLPurifier is not sufficient on it's own. It's just an extra layer to avoid things like cross-site attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Never escape data into a presentation format before putting it in a database; sanitize it if appropriate, but always have the database contain the "rawest" form of the data.

Always escape data into a presentation format before displaying, unless it is certain that the data should not be escaped and that it is safe to not escape it.

Comment: Hi Ignacio. When you say that the database should contain the rawest information, what's your take on saving rich text? I'll add that I'm using filtered html because one consensus is that bbcode is more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @austinbv: There is **no** reason for your database to contain things like "&quot;"; it makes manipulating the data and non-HTML output more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: turning quotes to &quote; is not escaping or sanitizing you should be able to just escape the quote out of the sql so it would be $1 = \'hello\' and your query would be 'INSERT '.$1.' INTO...'

Comment: @austinbv: That's not the sort of escaping I'm talking about; not doing *that* properly would be trouble on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what your values are and where they are coming from.  The short and sweet answer is:

**ESCAPE AND SANITIZE**

which means make sure you put all strings in quotes and make sure you escape all special characters in user submitted strings.  Type match and length check.

Comment: What do you mean by "put all strings in quotes"? What special characters are you referring to?

Comment: Well if you have an input $1 and the sql statement 'INSERT '.$1.' INTO... SQL injection can occure by making $1 = ');PHP  The best approach is using prepared statement like with PDO

Comment: @austin in that case you *need* to use the library's sanitation function (like `mysql_real_escape_string`). Just adding slashes or quotes creates security holes. Or use prepared statements, as you say

Comment: So, to reformulate the idea is to escape input (to avoid injection I assume) and to match type (int for example?) and check the maximum length we're expecting? Will check out preparedstatements (sounds like Java) and will later think about switching to PDO if necessary.

Comment: @pekka special characters are characters that could break your current sql statement and lead to injection.  So if all your sql statements are contained in single quotes then single quotes in submitted responses should iirc be escaped by ` \ ` or by replacing the `'` with something safe and reconverting later.  Or just not allowing specific characters to be inserted into the db. like why allow single quotes for a phone number or username

Comment: Prepared statements look like an odd syntax for new developers but make sense your query would look like this query('INSERT ? INTO ...', $1);  And the prepared statement would replace the ? token with an escaped and sanitized $1

Comment: @austin this is all correct and good background info, but all those things *must* be covered by the sanitation function of your library (or the function preparing the statements). So to clarify, there is no need to do this by hand.

Comment: @pekka I am not saying do it by hand, but the question asked what should be done before you insert. I answered kinda under the assumption they are not using a db class or that the asker was just interested in what the db classes do and why it is important. Also in my first big web project I designed my own db class that sanitized on its own, you don't have to trust a library or framework . It can be done on your own. :)

Comment: @Pekka: Do you have any libraries to recommend? It sounds like there's some useful addons out there.
@austinbv: Looks very similar to PrepareStatements in Java so I should be ok :)

Comment: @James the hot topic in php right now is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It has some awesome features that really can aid in db manipulation.

Comment: @austinbv: Yes, I came accross the mention of PDO a couple of times. It sounds like a move to database independance through a driver (akin to JDBC on Java and ADO on .NET). It's a definite move forward.