# Making MySQL queries safe for database insertion (strings)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practises for getting information from $_GET/$_POST and saving it to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748065/practises-for-getting-information-from-get-post-and-saving-it-to-a-database)

Just wondering what exactly I should look out for with regards to safety in MySQL database insertions for users entering strings.

Currently all I'm doing is `mysql_real_escape_string($string)` for every $_GET or $_POST input I wish to put in the database. Is that cool? What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO friend_request (ToUID, FromUID) VALUES (?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $fid, $uid); //i-> Integer, S -> string
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
 echo 'Request Sent';
else
 echo 'Something went wrong !';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my process:

```
//check to see if the request came from your server or not
$server = substr($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER],0,LENGTH OF INCOMING PAGE);
$prevPage = ""; //the incoming page
if ($server != $prevPage) {
    header("Location: $prevPage");
    exit;
} else {
    //pull and sanitize the data
    include('link.php'); //include the link to your database
    $var = $link->mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);

    //check for null values in required fields

    //run the data through a regular expression check

    //then store the information
```

There is so much more you could do to validate the data being entered.

Comment: You do understand that a http client can easily fake a referrer header, right?

Comment: Yes, but it is just extra validation code.

Comment: I guess I'll rephrase my question - is mysql_real_escape_string enough?

Comment: For a production web app no. If you think that a real_escape is enough then thats your opinion. It's all up to you.